How to dynamically patch a prototypal class method without the usage of the super keyword?
class bcomp {
 some(){
    console.log("bcomp");
 }
}
class acomp extends bcomp {
 some(){
    super.some();
    console.log("acomp");
 }
}
var ins = new acomp();
ins.some()

so output will be
bcomp
acomp

I need to override some method of acomp with super keyword
acomp.prototype.some = function (params) {
    super.some();
    console.log("new acomp");
}

SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here

How to achieve the above?

You seem to already be in hacking territory, if you're attempting to monkey-patch a method on an existing class. At that point, why are you then limiting yourself to super?

"I need to [use] super keyword" - why? If all you want to do is call bcomp.prototype.some, you don't need super for that.

Call the some method of the parent class directly like this
bcomp.prototype.some.call(this);

instead of super.some()

A generic patch approach for some which targets an objects 2nd prototype within this objects prototype chain without having to know the object's/instance's involved classes would make use of Object.getPrototypeOf twice.
In addition one should make use of Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor together with Reflect.defineProperty in order to patch this new some method in its most correct way.


function root(value) {
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(value);
}

// new prototypal `AComp` method.
function some() {

  // // `BComp.prototype`
  // root(
  // 
  //   // `AComp.prototype`
  //   root(this)
  // )
  // ?.some();

  // root(root(this))?.some();

  root(root(this))?.some.call(this);

  console.log("new acomp");
}

Reflect.defineProperty(
  AComp.prototype, 'some', {
    ...Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(AComp.prototype, 'some'),
    value: some,
  },
);

(new AComp).some();
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
class BComp {
 some(){
    console.log("bcomp");
 }
}
class AComp extends BComp {
 some(){
    super.some();
    console.log("acomp");
 }
}
</script>




"In addition one should make use of Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor together with Reflect.defineProperty in order to patch this new some method in its most correct way." - why is that? The assignment the OP made doesn't change writability or enumerability either. And both methods work only when it's a data property. Btw I would recommend not to use Reflect outside of proxy handlers and prefer the normal Object.defineProperty/.getOwnPropertyDescriptor methods here.

@Bergi ... in case one does not know any more details about how some was implemented, except that it is a prototype method, but one wants to assign the patched some with the correct descriptor properties <Object|Reflect>.<getOwnPropertyDescriptor|defineProperty> is the only possible solution.

JS is a prototypical language but at the same time it is a functional language. It's best not to modify the prototype methods once they are set. As i remember they are costly operations. Instead it's a reasonable approach to make the some function to accept the desired functionality.


class bcomp {
 some(){
    console.log("bcomp");
 }
}
class acomp extends bcomp {
 #f;
 some(f = this.#f || (_ => console.log("acomp"))) {
    this.#f = f;
    super.some()
    this.#f();
 }
}
var ins = new acomp();
ins.some();                              // uses defaut action
ins.some(_ => console.log("new acomp")); // sets #f and makes it the new default action.
ins.some()                               // uses the new default action




You typically don't re-write a method when you still have full control over the original code. So modifying the child in the first place is probably not a solution. If it could have been modified, no overwriting would be needed.

Also, a method that accepts a function to execute as its body is certainly an odd choice. It probably means you don't need a method at all, if (almost) all it does is something defined externally.

@VLAZ That's what exactly i am doing here. some is a fixed prototype function which accepts a function to make it the default functionality and then runs, if provided. I believe this is, for whatever reason the OP requires it, the most suitable solution.
